# Access Mysql container from a different machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mysql-workbench, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm up and running in a set of computers [A,B,C] ,these host machines are all running centOS . I have my own computer running windows 10 [Z],with Mysql Workbench installed .
How can I connect from Z  to the mysql instances running on A,B or C.
When I deploy the stack using my compose file the names of the docker containers are appended with a random string ,and this command

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .Name }} => {{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -a -q)
```

is not able to list out the ip's of the individual containers.
It just lists the container names .
I do have the data for the Mysql container maintained in a volume ,and the port mapping in the compose file as

```
3306:3306
```

What can I do to make this work ?

Comment: Your three mysql instances (M1, M2 and M3) are bound each to an host server (M1 -> A, M2 -> B, M3 -> C) ? And you map 3306 of each one to its host? You should be able to connect to A,B and C on port 3306. But, what if a host dies? Could you post your stack configuration?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear about it earlier , A is manger and B and C asre workers ,The compose file has a restriction [node.role == manager] ,for the mysql container ,so it will spawn only on machine A .There are no replicas of this container.

Comment: When connecting from workbench it needs two ip's the SSH hostname and the MySQL hostname ,  So the SSH host name would be the IP of Machine A ,and MYSQL host name would be 127.0.0.1 ,ie localhost ?

Comment: To sum it up, you have a single mysql container (M) running **only** on A with port mapping 3306:3306 ? Point mysqlworkbench directly on A:3306